# Issue with Ionic/Cordova Google Maps Plugin

Tags: android, google-maps, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am developing an app which shows the live tracking of the vehicle through GPS.

Everything is working fine. But the map is not rendering. Any help would be helpful.

### Points I have double checked

- API Key is integrated in package.json, config.xml and android.json.
- Same API Key is showing responses when used on Webpages.

### Help I need

- Anyone who understand the issue.
- Is there any tool so that we can check the log of running apk on android/iOS device.

[image: Map is not rendering]

Answer (score 0):

You can check the logs of running android application on your phone using Chrome.

**For android:**

1. Connect your phone to PC through USB cable and make sure **USB
   Debugging mode** is enabled on your phone ( Go to Developer options
   in settings and enable USB Debugging mode).
2. Open chrome browser on your PC and type **chrome://inspect** in the
   URL. You will be taken to Chrome's **DevTools** page. Your device
   will be listed under **Remote Target** section.Find your application
   name in the list of debuggable apps, click on inspect and start
   debugging.

I have attached the image for reference

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Gray map is api key problem. Please check your api key. 
https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps-doc/blob/master/troubleshootings/graymap/README.md